# part of user input inside command file and part in terminal for fortran script

Tags: bash, fortran

I have a fortran program that requires a lot of user input. I have written a command file to deal with most of the read(*,*) statements in the code. At some point however, the fortran code enters a do loop where I would like the read(*,*) commands to then be directed to the terminal so that I can enter them manually rather than be inputted from the .command file. Is there a cheap and nasty way to do this?

I currently use a here document format to supply the answers to the read(*,*) statements in the code, but am just unsure how to switch from .command script from shell script without killing the program. I made a simple example below to illustrate the problem...

e.g (fortran script)

```
{

program testcommand

write(*,*) 'enter a: '

read(*,*) a

write(*,*) 'enter b: '

read(*,*) b


write(*,*) a, b

end program

}
```

I then run this script using the command file

```
{

gfortran gfrot.f90

./a.out <<< "

10

8

"

}
```

Say if I want the  value of a to be specified in the script, and then b to be specified in the terminal, is such a thing doable?

Comment: why not modify the fortran to read what you want from a file?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed a command substitution that reads and outputs a value into the here document.

```
./a.out <<EOF
10
$(read X; echo "$X")
EOF
```

Alternately, you can feed the Fortran program with a small script writes output directly to standard input, calling `read` when necessary.

```
{ echo 10;
  read B;
  echo "$B"; } | a.out
```

Comment: Would it also be possible to write a here document to state the first value of n in the script below, and then allow the user to input whether they wish to continue in the terminal (i.e the value of 'nagain'). The problem is I dont know how many times I will be returning to the start.                                                        program testcommand
! script to add the numbers 1 to n
1 write(*,*) 'enter n: '
read(*,*) 10
do i = 1,n
sum = sum +i
enddo
write(*,*) 'The sum is:', n
write(*,*) 'would you like to go again (1 or 0)?'
read(*,*) nagain

if (nagain == 1) goto 1
end program

Comment: That was terrible formatting! Basically can I have the here document write to the screen mid way through inputting all the fortran inputs? Also, is there an equivalent of goto in the here document (ie return to an earlier line in the script and repeat)?

Comment: You might want to look into `expect`, which is designed for programmatically interacting with an interactive program. A here document is designed to be a dynamic file, not a script itself. The hack I showed in the first example is probably about as far as you want to go before just writing a script that calculates and outputs the input expected by the other program.